# How to use prop spreading and extracting props at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components like this

```
const TextLarge = (props) => { // props are classes,color and children
    return <Text
               classes={'text-large-style'}
               {...props}>
               {props.children}
           </Text>
}

const Text = ({
    children,
    color,
    classes,
}) => {
    return <p
               className={clsx('text-styles', classes)}
               style={{color: color}}>
               {children}
           </p>
}
```

Now, when I pass a `class` to `<TextLarge />`

```
<TextLarge
    classes='some-special-style'>
    Foo
<TextLarge>
```

This overwrites `classes='text-large-style'` because `{...props}` spreads `classes='some-special-style` into `<TextLarge/>` *after* `classes='text-large-style`.

Is there a (React/elegant) way to take `classes` out of `props`, so something like

```
const TextLarge = (props) => { // props are classes,color and children
    return <Text
               classes={clsx('text-large-style', props.classes)}
               {...props}> // no classes in here
               {props.children}
           </Text>
}
```

yet still spreading the rest of the `{...props}` into `<Text />`?
I know that could change the order, making `classes={clsx('text-large-style', props.classes)}` overwrite `{...props}`

```
const TextLarge = (props) => { // props are classes,color and children
    return <Text
               {...props}
               classes={clsx('text-large-style', props.classes)}>
               {props.children}
           </Text>
}
```

but I want more control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a (React/elegant) way to take classes out of props

Yes, you can use destructuring with a rest target:

```
const TextLarge = ({classes, ...rest}) => {
    // ...
};
```

Actually, you probably want to remove `children` as well:

```
const TextLarge = ({classes, children, ...rest}) => {
    // ...
};
```

Then `...rest` won't include `classes` (or `children`), and you can include `classes` in your explicit prop (**if** you want to pass them on):

```
const TextLarge = ({classes, children, ...rest}) => {
    return (
        <Text {...rest} classes={`text-large-style ${classes ?? ""}`}>
            {children}
        </Text>
    );
};
```

Comment: Ah nice, thats clean and neat. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!